# React env file not working on IIS remote server

Tags: reactjs, iis, environment-variables, windows-server-2008

I built and deployed a react project on a remote server. However I have discovered that the env is nowhere to be found, or else react is not picking it up. The env file has some API URLs which were all working fine on my local machine.

I have one for dev. and prod. in the root folder.

This is the script aspect of `package.json`

How can I make this work?

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.dev react-scripts start",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.prod react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: 1 - What command are you using to start your application on the remote server?
2 - Are you really sure you are deploying the .env.prod file with your application?

Comment: .I didnt use any command. I deployed the build files

Comment: Are you sure that the command `env-cmd` is also available on the remote server? And if it is available, are you sure you can run them without adding them to path? From what I read, `env-cmd` is an npm package and should not be available on the remote server.

Comment: I ran ```npm build``` and moved the build files to the server. I can redeploy with the right steps. can please tell me the steps to take.

Comment: The .env files are not part of the build, so you have to deploy them separately, or find another way to add the environment variables to your server. One you run the build command, the environment variables will be used, but once the script is done running, they will no longer be accessible (I am not sure if this was clear, the point is that they will no longer be accessible after the build). Where are you deploying to?

Comment: Redeploy your application: https://dev.to/sumitkharche/how-to-deploy-react-application-on-iis-server-1ied

Comment: @TheobaldDu I redeployed but the config file, it broke my app. I have to remove it. and but the config still not working

Comment: @TheobaldDu I have to install url-rewrite as suggested in the article. I omitted that part. thanks. Everything is working fine now